# Can a Cohort and Familiar be the same NPC?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, familiars

Assuming the NPC species/type/subtype would be a valid choice for both the cohort and familiar features.

For the sake of a complete example, lets take a Coure Eladrin.

- Wizard is CG, has the exalted familiar feat, and is lv 20 (Can have a coure eladrin as familiar).
- Wizard has the leadership feat, and over 25 leadership score (even though 25 is the cap). Has no cohort at the moment.
- Wizard currently has no familiar, and is not on *"familiar replacement cooldown"*.
- Wizard has access to the eladrin homeland in Arborea, and several coure are willing to go into wizard's service. Permission from the higher ups is also assumed.

Can the wizard take a **Coure with class levels** (within the ECL allowed by the Leadership feat) and  **make that Coure the wizard's familiar**?

Or does the wizard **must walk out with two coures**, one with class levels and another with the basic outsider 2 HD?

The DM is indifferent on the subject but would prefer to stick to the written rules. What do the books say?

Comment: Note that Familiars and Cohorts have different advancement rules, and that those rules might conflict with each other when it comes time to figure out what level the... ah... (Familhort? Comiliar?), entity would be.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I want to ask if I can have my cake, cast [Alamir's Fundamental Breakdown](http://dungeonsdragons.wikia.com/wiki/Alamir%27s_Fundamental_Breakdown) on it and then eat it too. @nijineko

Answer (score 2):

The rules don't mention the possibility of a familiar *also* being a cohort due to the master having taken the feat [Leadership](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#leadership) (*Player's Handbook* 97). However, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on Paladin Cohort Mounts provides rules that can be massaged to fit:

> At the DM’s option, she may allow a paladin or other character with a special mount class feature to combine the special mount with the cohort feat [n.b. in context, the feat Leadership]. The special qualities such as the empathic link and shared spells make this quite potent and worth a minimum of a +2 level adjustment to the cohort mount ECL. (200)

The typical coure (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 168-9) has a cohort level adjustment of +5 for an effective character level (ECL) of 7. Using the above Paladin Cohort Mounts as a guideline—and assuming that the DM rules that the special abilities a wizard grants his familiar are as "potent" as the special abilities a paladin grants her special mount—this makes the cohort familiar coure ECL 9, and such a cohort familiar becomes a possibility for any creature with the appropriate feats and a leadership score of at least 13.

The only real sticking point *after* that is the creature's Hit Dice and hp. Were a player to come to me with this proposal, I think I'd use the master's effective Hit Dice for computing spell effects (as per [Familiars](http://dndsrd.net/wizard.html#familiars) on Hit Dice on *PH* 52) *plus* whatever Hit Dice the creature gains naturally due to its own advancement beyond this then follow a similar procedure for the creature's hit points—half the master's hp plus whatever hp are gained from advancement. This will make the familiar's effective Hit Dice higher than the master's—and that's weird—, but since the creature doesn't really benefit all that much from it, that shouldn't be a big deal.

If the DM *won't* adapt the Paladin Cohort Mounts rules to familiars, then it looks like the wizard is stuck with having two sprites, one a familiar, the other a cohort from the feat Leadership.

Comment: Wouldn't it be **either** the Advanced HD or the Wizard's level? The rules say *"use the master’s character level or the familiar’s normal HD total, whichever is higher."* - first generate the NPC stats with class levels, then decide to either use one or another.

Comment: @Mindwin That could totally work—I mean, we're *already* in house rules territory, so have fun!—, but I think that would negate an advantage of the familiar also being a cohort. Besides, those effective Hit Dice don't really *do* anything except, like, help the creature resist effects like *sleep.*

Comment: On the last paragraph, the whole point of this exercise is to see if there is anything (in the books) against cutting down on the *heavenly fairy mischief* that would ensue from RP all those faeries going bananas in the dungeon.

Comment: But if there is the precedent for the paladin to mix both in the DMG, there is no reason the wiz can't use it too.

Comment: @Mindwin I totally get not *wanting* to be surrounded by a cloud of chaotic, pranking angels. `;-)` Honestly, I've no idea why the wizard and the druid and the ranger couldn't do the same as the paladin. I suspect—with absolutely nothing but my gut to back it up—someone just wanted his or her  paladin to ride something awesomer than what was immediately available, so somebody wrote those rules. Again, I suspect *lack of foresight* as the culprit rather than *gross imbalance shall ensue!* Hell, we're talking about a level 20 wizard here. He could have Ftr20 cohort and probably be fine.

Comment: 17th. The max level for a cohort before [tag:Epic-Tier] is 17th `:)`

Comment: @Mindwin So the Wiz20 could *cheat* and have a Ftr20 cohort and likely no one would notice. `;-)`

Comment: You could put them in a familiar pocket, and target them with spells that are familiar-specific. Has anyone ever done a build that attempt to pile on as many familiar/cohort/animal companion/mount/etc., type's as possibly can fit onto one character? (waits for someone to make a friendship reference...)

Comment: @nijineko (In a campaign I'm running now one of the PCs is accumulating familiars *via* the feat Extra Familiar so that with them he can share his soulmelds. He's just gotten familiar #2. By binding the soulmeld *soulspark familiar* to his crown chakra, that PC is a party of 6… at level 6.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan there is a prestige class (or was it base class...) in the WotC official DragonLance books which gained 4 cohorts over the course of the class. Take a level of psion or erudite for the psicrystal, a couple levels of druid or ranger for the animal companion, a few of paly for the mount and perhaps some thrall herd for two cohorts.... That's just off the top of my head. So, out of curiosity, how do you handle their turn not dominating by sheer dint of time it takes to resolve all those actions? Or should I make that a question all by itself - might be handy?

Comment: @nijineko (If the familiars stray beyond 5 ft. of the master, the soulmelds can't be shared. If a soulspark familiar strays beyond 10 ft. of its master, the soulmeld unshapes. So, fortunately, Team Jalas has to remain pretty tightly clustered rather than scattering across the battlefield, which would be a mess. Otherwise, they're all just making ranged touch attacks (Jalas and the familiars with *dissolving spittle* and the soulspark familiars with their soul blasts), which are pretty uncomplicated.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan So you have a squishy wiz-type who has to charge directly into the fray.... Somehow I see this as a rage mage or a green star adept.... I hope they are at least pranking the enemies or taking a whiz on them for distraction/flanking value or something *useful*. ^^

Comment: @nijineko (Not *that* squishy, really. Con's Jalas's highest stat followed by Dex, so he can take a hit *and* evade them—plus *mage armor* and stuff, of course. And he and his familiar buddies will gladly provoke attacks of opportunity as he typically shapes and shares the *mantle of flame* soulmeld. It's a *terrible* build in a high-op campaign, but it's devastatingly effective in semi-Tier-3 campaign that Jalas is in.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan so many really FUN builds are just like that....